# Delete old data in table after copy and paste macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

I have developed a working macro in VBA that automatically opens a workbook and then copies the data and pastes it on a table in the workbook I am working on. I perform this task monthly.

The data set varies in rows every month but does not vary in columns.

I am running into issues when the data set in less rows than the previous month and I am forced to manually delete lines that remained in the table because the previous month had more rows.

I was hoping to add to my existing code to automatically delete the old data after pasting the new data.

I perform a manual keystroke of selecting the last row of new data and move down one cell in column A then do a Ctrl+Shift+Down+Right to grab the data and select delete. So essentially that is the task I am trying to replace.

Thanks.

```
Sub Import_File()

    Dim wbSourceData As Workbook
    Dim wbDestination As Workbook
    Dim wsSourceData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim strFName As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim Cl As Long
    Dim Rl As Long
    

    Set wbDestination = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsDestination = wbDestination.Sheets("DataTab")
    
    strFName = wbDestination.Worksheets("Macros").Range("C2").Value
    
    Set wbSourceData = Workbooks.Open(strFName)
    Set wsSourceData = wbSourceData.Worksheets(3)
    
    Set tbl = wsDestination.ListObjects("Data_Report")
    
    tbl.DataBodyRange.ClearContents
    
    With wsSourceData
    Cl = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(Rl, Cl))
    End With

    rng.Copy
    wsDestination.Range("A4").PasteSpecial xlValues
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    wbSourceData.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: If you're working with a true table (`ListObject`), then why not use `ListObject.DataBodyRange.ClearContents` before pasting the new data?

Comment: The data set is thousands of rows. I have manually deleted all but the first row of data in the table making the table one row long before running my copy and paste macro. I felt this takes significantly longer to paste the data into the table that way. Usually the data set varies within a couple hundred rows so I felt it would take less memory in the macro to delete the extra rows after the copy and paste versus clearing all the data and then pasting thousands of rows.

Comment: Eh, clearing contents should be pretty fast.

Comment: `Dim tbl As ListObject`

`Set tbl = DataTab.ListObjects("Data_Report")`

`ListObject.DataBodyRange.ClearContents`

Comment: Above is what I have in my code. I was wondering if this was correct. I set my variables. The worksheet the table is on is called "DataTab" and the name of the table is called "Data_Report".

Comment: `tbl.DataBodyRange.ClearContents`.

Comment: You are correct, this is pretty fast. This does a goo job of clearing the contents but then I am left with blank rows at the bottom of my table and the table does not auto resize

Answer (score 0):

### Overwrite Data Body Range

- It is assumed that only values of the range will be copied.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub overwriteDataBodyRangeTEST()
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range("G2:K11")
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = DataTab.ListObjects("Data_Report")
    overwriteDataBodyRange rg, tbl
End Sub

Sub overwriteDataBodyRange( _
        ByVal rg As Range, _
        ByVal tbl As ListObject)
    
    With tbl.DataBodyRange
        Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
        Dim tCount As Long: tCount = .Rows.Count
        If rg.Columns.Count = .Columns.Count Then
            .Resize(rCount).Value = rg.Value
            If rCount < tCount Then
                 .Resize(tCount - rCount).Offset(rCount).Delete
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Different number of columns.", vbCritical, "Fail"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

### EDIT

- The following will copy the range to the table overwriting the previous data. If the previous data has more rows, they will be deleted.

**Integrated**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Import_File()
    
    ' Define Destination Table.
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets("DataTab")
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = dws.ListObjects("Data_Report")
    
    ' Define Source Range.
    Dim sName As String: sName = dwb.Worksheets("Macros").Range("C2").Value
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sName)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(3)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    With sws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastColumn = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
    End With
    
    ' Copy Source Range to Destination Table.
    With tbl.DataBodyRange
        Dim tCount As Long: tCount = .Rows.Count
        Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rng.Rows.Count
        .Resize(rCount).Value = rng.Value ' values only
        'rng.Copy .Resize(rCount) ' values, formats, and formulas
        If rCount < tCount Then
             .Resize(tCount - rCount).Offset(rCount).Delete
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Close Source Workbook (it was just read from).
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: I edited my post and listed my code above. I added the `tbl.DataBodyRange.ClearContents` code that was recommended by @BigBen however this is not ideal as this just clears the table. I am looking to clear the table and then delete any extra rows. Looking at your code that you posted as the answer I was wondering why you are using two different Subs and not just one macro. I am trying to integrate your code with what I have listed in mine but am struggling. I'm still a beginner in VBA so please ELI5. Thank you.

Comment: In your code, after `End With`, use the line `overwriteDataBodyRange rng, tbl` instead of your two copy/paste lines.

Comment: Is there anything else I need to add. I updated the bottom of my code with this
    `With wsSourceData
    Cl = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(Rl, Cl))
    End With

    overwriteDataBodyRange rng, tbl
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False`

I am getting a compile error. I did not change any of my dimensions or variables from  my original code.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot figure out how to get the format to appear cleaner

Comment: In your answer you have two Subs. In my original code I only have one Sub. I was wondering if it is possible to complete this code only using one Sub?

Comment: That is exactly what you should have done. Now, in which line do you get the compile error and what does it say?

Comment: "Sub or Function not defined"

I get the error in the line `overwriteDataBodyRange rng, tbl`

Comment: I guess you will have to copy my second code into a standard module e.g. `Module1`, or to the same module where your code is, so it can be found by your procedure.

Comment: What is the purpose of the Module?`Sub overwriteDataBodyRangeTEST()
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range("G2:K11")
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = DataTab.ListObjects("Data_Report")
    overwriteDataBodyRange rg, tbl
End Sub`

Comment: That's not a module, that's a procedure. Its purpose is to show how to use the `overwriteDataBodyRange` procedure: define the range, define the table and call the procedure with `overwriteDataBodyRange range, table`. Other contributors may find it useful, too.

Comment: I am still struggling with your code. I think I would need to see the entire code updated rather than you trying to explain to me to cut one part out edit, it is unfortunately confusing me since I am a beginner . If you look at my original code and add this line at the end I believe this should work. I am just getting a 1004 error that "run time error 1004 delete method of range class failed". I put this at the very bottom of my code after the line that starts with `wbSourceData.Close` I add this this. `tbl.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: The reason I think this logic will work is because I am using the code `tbl.DataBodyRange.ClearContents` earlier in my code. If after my copy/paste macro there is a smaller data set than the previous month then there will be extra blanks rows. If I add to the bottom of my code to delete empty rows I would think that would then just delete the entire rows and then essentially resize my table for me. I just think the code needs tweaking since I am getting error 1004